How to use KVM and Bind in same network?
I have NAS with Ubuntu 20.04 and virtual machine (KVM) on it. Also I have Bind at host it serve not only guests machines, it works external LAN either. I use Bind for getting access all web sites of my network for VM.
When I turn on the NAS, my virtual machine does not start automatically because it cannot start one of many virtual machine networks:
error: Failed to start network Isolated
error: internal error: Child process (VIR_BRIDGE_NAME=virbr1 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/Isolated.conf --leasefile-ro --dhcp-script=/usr/lib/libvirt/libvirt_leaseshelper) unexpected exit status 2: 
dnsmasq: failed to create listening socket for 192.168.10.1: Address already in use

192.168.10.* these IPs user only for VM.
netstat -nlp | grep 192.168.10.1 - result is none.
I notice if I do:
service bind9 stop
virsh net-start Isolated
service bind9 start

When I start VM I have no errors. And Bind works fine.
Bind's settings.
acl "home" {127.0.0.0/24; 192.168.1.0/24; 192.168.10.0/24;};
options {
...
        listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; 192.168.1.10; 192.168.10.1; };
        allow-query { home; };
};

Any ideas on how to get it to work correctly are welcome.
